# Form output to multiple spans of the same class with JavaScript+IE8 support

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I've been learning as I go, but my current use of GetElementsbyClassName isn't working. I have a function, that when clicked should output the input field value, defined by ID, to multiple spans that are share a single class.

I had it working successfully outputting to the same ElementId, but because the users entry must be repeated in the document I have to use classes. I also need to use this code to get IE8 compatibility.

```
    function getElementsByClassName(node, classname) {
        var a = [];
        var re = new RegExp('(^| )'+classname+'( |$)');
        var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
            if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);
        return a;

}
var tabs = getElementsByClassName(document.body,'tab');
```

Does this go inside of my existing function?

Do I need to put the spans in a div?, or some other container for them to be successfully targeted?

In Javascript I have

function sayHi(){

```
  var BPCIN= document.getElementById("BPCIN");
  var OUTBPC = document.getElementsByClassName("OUTBPC")
  var name = BPCIN.value;
  OUTBPC.innerHTML = " " +name+ "";
```

In HTML I have

```
<span class="OUTBPC">SAY IT FIRST</span>

<span class="OUTBPC">SAY IT AGAIN</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to gather together all the DOM nodes with the specified class, like so (using your IE8-compatible `getElementsByClassName` function):

```
var els = getElementsByClassName(document.body,'OUTBPC');
```

then you want to iterate over them, setting each ones `innerHTML` property:

```
for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  els[i].innerHTML = " " + name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the problem of the RegExp, try this:

`function getElementsByClassName(node, classname) {
    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp("\\s+" + classname + "\\s+");
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
        if(re.test(" " + els[i].className + " "))a.push(els[i]);
    return a;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
 //IE8
 function getElementsByClassName(node, classname)
{
    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp('\\b' + classname + '\\b');
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
        if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);
    return a;
}
 //What you want is to gather together all the DOM nodes with the specified class, like so (using your IE8-compatible getElementsByClassName function):


  function sayHi(){



  var BPCIN= document.getElementById("BPCIN");
  var els = getElementsByClassName(document.body,'OUTBPC');
  var name = BPCIN.value;
 for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  els[i].innerHTML = " " + name;
}
```